# Change Element content in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I got below XML in file "test.xml"

```
<MainDoc version="1.0" application="App2">
  <property name="AutoHiddenPanelCaptionShowMode">ShowForAllPanels</property>
  <property name="DockingOptions" isnull="true" iskey="true">
    <property name="DockPanelInTabContainerTabRegion">DockImmediately</property>
  </property>
  <property name="Panels" iskey="true" value="4">
    <property name="Item1" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Text">ContainerABC</property>
      <property name="Options" isnull="true" iskey="true">
        <property name="AllowFloating">true</property>
      </property>
    </property>
    <property name="Item2" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Text">ContainerXYZ</property>
    </property>
    <property name="Item3" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Text">Container123</property>
    </property>
    <property name="Item4" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Text">panelContainer1</property>
    </property>
  </property>
</MainDoc>
```

I want to change element content where it says "panelContainer1" to "Container456" above.  How can I do that.  I tried below but not sure how to get to that content and change it.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlPath = @"C:\Downloads\test.xml";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
            var items = from item in doc.Descendants("property")
                        where item.Attribute("name").Value == "Item4"
                        select item;
            foreach (XElement itemElement in items)
            {
                //something here ?
            }
        }
```

Comment: `itemElement.Value = "Container456";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is looking good. and what you need is `itemElement.Value`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var items = doc.Root.Descendants("property")
                    .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Item4")
                    .Descendants()
                    .Where(x=> x.Attribute("name").Value == "Text");

foreach(var itemElement in items)
{
    itemElement.Value = "Container456";
}

doc.Save(xmlPath);
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna, this is good.  But what if there are more elements like <property name="Text">panelContainer1</property> and also property name="Visibility">Visible</property> then how to filter only to get "panelContainer1"?

Comment: @kami, I have updated my post to address the scenario. Please check

Comment: This is good. Many thanks.  Only last thing that this change is not being made to "test.xml" file.  How that can be done?

Comment: @kami, please check the updated post. you just need doc.save

Comment: Simple and great.  Thanks again @Krishna